# Collective maximum

Tags: sql

I have a table structure like this:

```
employee
    id int
    manager_id int (the employee id of the manager)
    name
    ...

awards
    id int
    employee_id int
    points int (the award "value")
```

How can I find the manager whose staff (those who report directly to the manager) have collectively the most awards points?

Comment: JOIN on employee.id = awards.employee_id, GROUP BY manager, do a SUM on points, ORDER BY points, and take the TOP 1, LIMIT 1 or Row_Number <= 1 (depending on the database)

Comment: Can you give an example of data and the results you want?  Your question is ambiguous, because you don't say if you are referring only to direct reports.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Direct reports - the question has been edited to reflect this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this:

```
SELECT
    mgr.id,
    mgr.name,
    SUM(awd.points) As TotalStaffPoints
FROM    employee As mgr
JOIN    employee As stf ON mgr.id = stf.manager_id
JOIN    awards   As awd ON stf.id = awd.employee_id
GROUP BY mgr.id, mgr.name
ORDER BY TotalStaffPoints DESC
```

Comment: probably want some `GROUP BY` in there to make it proper but this is the general idea

Comment: @Bohemian: Trying to get a hat?  ;-)

Answer (score 2):

```
select top 1 employee.manager_id, SUM(awards.points) as total
from employee
join awards on employee.id = awards.employee_id
group by employee.manager_id
order by SUM(awards.points) desc
```